# Obtain all keys x from an array of objects (php, laravel blade)

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The database table looks like this:

[image]

The "extras" column in the database is storing an array of objects that look like this:

```
[
{"id":92,"product_id":8966,"extra_type":"Extras","extra_name":"Olives"},

{"id":93,"product_id":8966,"extra_type":"Extras","extra_name":"Ketchup"},

{"id":92,"product_id":8966,"extra_type":"Extras","extra_name":"Olives"}
]
```

The code below (from the Laravel blade) returns the array of objects.

```
@foreach($item->orderedProducts as $op)
<tr>
     <td>
         <span>{{ $op['extras'] }}</span><br>
     </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

$op returns this:

```
{
  "id": 171,
  "product_id": 8966,
  "order_id": 175,
  "price": 11,
  "count": 1,
  "product_data": "{\"id\":8966,\"name\":\"Camera Br\\u00fbl\\u00e9e\",\"description\":\"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit etiam, conubia tempus sed dapibus augue gravida accumsan. Odio congue in blandit iaculis risus gravida parturient dictum quis rhoncus volutpat ornare tincidunt, dignissim ut pellentesque.\",\"price\":11,\"price_old\":null,\"category_id\":4584,\"created_at\":\"2019-03-17 14:59:56\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-04-17 16:37:03\",\"tax_group_id\":null,\"sort\":1,\"vendor_id\":null,\"option1\":null,\"option2\":null,\"option3\":null,\"option4\":null,\"option5\":null,\"option6\":null,\"images\":[\"http:\\/\\/localhost:8000\\/product_images\\/ElI9GImttc.jpg\"],\"formatted_price\":\"\\u00a311\",\"formatted_old_price\":\"0\",\"tax_value\":0,\"city_id\":null,\"restaurant_id\":null,\"product_images\":[{\"id\":9000,\"image\":\"\\/product_images\\/ElI9GImttc.jpg\",\"product_id\":8966,\"created_at\":\"2019-04-08 15:16:53\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-04-08 15:16:53\"}],\"tax_group\":null,\"category\":{\"id\":4584,\"name\":\"Random Things\",\"_lft\":1,\"_rgt\":2,\"parent_id\":null,\"created_at\":\"2018-11-09 13:15:01\",\"updated_at\":\"2019-04-17 16:47:21\",\"restaurant_id\":null,\"city_id\":null,\"category_image\":null,\"has_children\":0,\"image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/localhost:8000\\/category_images\\/a64be5a696402b0fe3649536ab6a49e4_1555519641.jpg\"},\"added\":true}",
  "extras": "[{\"id\":93,\"product_id\":8966,\"extra_type\":\"Extras\",\"extra_name\":\"Ketchup\",\"extra_price\":\"1.20\",\"extra_added\":true,\"price_sum\":1.2,\"extra_count\":1}]",
  "exclusions": "[{\"id\":117,\"product_id\":8966,\"extra_type\":\"Exclusions\",\"extra_name\":\"Rat poison\",\"extra_price\":null,\"exclusion_added\":true}]",
  "created_at": "2019-04-27 10:35:11",
  "updated_at": "2019-04-27 10:35:11",
  "product": {
    "id": 8966,
    "name": "Camera Brûlée",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit etiam, conubia tempus sed dapibus augue gravida accumsan. Odio congue in blandit iaculis risus gravida parturient dictum quis rhoncus volutpat ornare tincidunt, dignissim ut pellentesque.",
    "price": 11,
    "price_old": null,
    "category_id": 4584,
    "created_at": "2019-03-17 14:59:56",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-17 16:37:03",
    "tax_group_id": null,
    "sort": 1,
    "vendor_id": null,
    "option1": null,
    "option2": null,
    "option3": null,
    "option4": null,
    "option5": null,
    "option6": null,
    "images": [
      "http://localhost:8000/product_images/ElI9GImttc.jpg"
    ],
    "formatted_price": "£11",
    "formatted_old_price": "0",
    "tax_value": 0,
    "city_id": null,
    "restaurant_id": null,
    "product_images": [
      {
        "id": 9000,
        "image": "/product_images/ElI9GImttc.jpg",
        "product_id": 8966,
        "created_at": "2019-04-08 15:16:53",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-08 15:16:53"
      }
    ],
    "tax_group": null,
    "category": {
      "id": 4584,
      "name": "Random Things",
      "_lft": 1,
      "_rgt": 2,
      "parent_id": null,
      "created_at": "2018-11-09 13:15:01",
      "updated_at": "2019-04-17 16:47:21",
      "restaurant_id": null,
      "city_id": null,
      "category_image": null,
      "has_children": 0,
      "image_url": "http://localhost:8000/category_images/a64be5a696402b0fe3649536ab6a49e4_1555519641.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is obtain all the values of (for example) "extra_name" from "extras:".

The desired output should be something like:

Olives
Ketchup
Olives

Comment: Can you try `{{ $op->extras }}`?

Comment: You need `{{ $op->extra_type }}`, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
@foreach($item->orderedProducts as $op)
<tr>
    <td>
    @if ('Extras' == $op->extra_type)
         <span>{{ $op->extra_name }}</span><br>
    @endif
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will workout

```
@foreach($item->orderedProducts as $op)
<?php $array = stripslashes(json_encode($op->extras)) ?>
    <tr>
         <td>
             <span>
             @foreach($array as $value)
                 {{ $value['extra_name'] }}
             @endforeach
             </span><br>
         </td>
    </tr>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Can you please post what $op prints...by doing=> print_r($op) inside the first foreach

Comment: or you can try replacing $op['extras'] by $op->extras in 2nd foreach

Comment: I have added what $op returns. Do you know why there are ' \ ' in the json?

Comment: ok, it is taken as string which is a json. Anyway you have to format "extras" before 2nd foreach to json format. then you are all done. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can access objects value by using `->` in laravel, try this

```
@foreach($item->orderedProducts as $op)
<tr>
 <td>
     <span>{{ $op->extra_name }}</span><br>
 </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. What I needed was to use `json_decode()` while iterating through an array of json objects. Next, I extracted the attributes I needed.

```
@foreach($item->orderedProducts as $op)
<tr>
    <td>
        @foreach(json_decode($op->extras, true) as $extra)
             {{ $extra['extra_name'] }}<br>
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```